# Sound wont play in button press

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

the code  I'm using to play the sound is this:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.m4a", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],currentSound.soundNameID];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = 0;

[player play];
```

I'm trying to play the sound but it wont play. my file is a `m4a` type.

Comment: Are you able to play other sound files? And can you print your soundFileURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if soundFileURL is OK, then I think the problem is that player is released before playing sound, declare player in header file.

Comment: you were right, but why whould the player be released before playing the sound?

Answer (score 0):

Add abn assert after each object creation to look for a nil object. Also don't do this in the button selector, put it into a block you dispatch to the main queue.